# Is it possible to create a custom Chrome installer with specific extentions that will be installed automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-app

I'm looking to be able to provide a Chrome installer that as they go through the wizard it installs Google Chrome as per normal, however it will also automatically install specific extentions from the App Store that will be there when they first open the browser.

Is there a tool available that would allow me to do this easily? I've done a number of searches on the topic but I have been successful.

Comment: Are you just looking to ship an installer for your chrome packaged application, and have it install the chrome runtime dependency, or, are you looking to install the chrome browser on a users machine with some extensions pre-bundled?

Comment: @mmocny I'm looking to install the chrome browser on a users machine with some extensions pre-bundled

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a list of extensions to be installed on first run of every new profile by using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions

So you'd just need to write a program that first lays this configuration down, and then runs the regular chrome installer.